# Can I Use 2 Different NVIDIA GPUs on this motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, gpu, dual-gpu

I'm planning to buy a new computer soon and I was wondering if I could put my old 1050ti with my current 2080ti on my new motherboard

here's the link for it - https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-x570-p/
(Asus Prime X570-P)

I'll be using the 1050ti for virtualization, so I'm probably going to disable it in my windows machine.

If I CAN use those two cards, will that affect the bandwidth of them?

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd card may be limited to 4 PCIe lanes. (Which will be hardly noticable, if at all.)
That will depend on the exact model of AMD CPU you have and how many NVMe M.2 SSD's you will be using. You will have to check the details of the manual for that.

**But another thing:**
NVidia drivers in Windows don't like it AT ALL if you got 2 cards with different architecture. In this case the 1050Ti is Pascal and the 2080Ti is Turing based.
The drivers can get in each other way badly. Crashing video-drivers on BOTH cards is a possibility. BSOD as well.

If you absolutely need to do this: Install the GeForce drivers for the oldest card (the 1050Ti) FIRST, reboot and then install the Geforce drivers for the newer card. That will give the highest chance of things working properly.

You may have to disable the 1050Ti in Windows completely to get a stable system.
(And think of this: Windows may re-enable the card spontaneously when pulling in driver-updates via WindowsUpdate or when upgrading to a new W10 version.)

You will also have to make sure Windows won't try to use its own buildin generic NVidia driver.
And Windows will re-enable that driver too on just about every major feature upgrade or driver update.

All in all: 2 different NVidia cards may be more hassle that it is worth...

Comment: That's new. I  thought you could run different generations for say phyX

Answer (score 0):

As per [The Fine Manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/PRIME_X570-P/E17441_PRIME_X570-P_UM_v3_WEB.pdf) - it depends on your GPU - and its something I've never seen before.

If you have a gen 1 or gen 2 ryzen CPU, the first slot and second slot work at x8 like nearly every other board I've seen.

With an 3rd or 4th gen GPU - The card in the first x16 slot will run at x16 (Put your 2080TI there!) and second slot will run at x4 (which is a bit meh, but I don't think the 1050ti will be bottlenecked that badly).

[image]

Its also worth remembering, depending on your CPU option, you may also have a vega adaptor - 'mixed' GPUs are supported in windows, and/or using that as the adaptor for your VM host in the other OS may be an option